# Como intercalar los datos de dos LinkedList?

Tags: java, colecciones

aprendiendo un poquito de Java me he cruzado con este ejercicio que me pide intercalar dos LinkedList para que esten ordenados pero sin un orden natural.

```
public class LinkedListPruebaEnlazada {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    LinkedList<String> paises = new LinkedList<String>();
    
    paises.add("España");
    paises.add("Colombia");
    paises.add("Mexico");
    paises.add("Perú");
    
    LinkedList<String> capitales = new LinkedList<String>();
    
    capitales.add("Madrid");
    capitales.add("Bogotá");
    capitales.add("Mexico DF");
    capitales.add("Lima");
    
}}
```

Ahora la duda que me surge es como poder ordenarlos de manera que la lista 1 sea la impar los elementos y la lista 2 sean par los elementos. Se que se puede hacer con un Iterador pero me preguntaba si existía alguna manera no muy compleja de darle este orden no natural a los elementos.

Yo solo conseguí unir las lista con este metodo.

```
List<String> paisesCapitales = new LinkedList<String>(paises);
    paisesCapitales.addAll(capitales);
```

pero ya no se como ordenarla para que el resultado quedara asi :

[España, Madrid, Colombia, Bogotá, Mexico, Mexico DF, Perú, Lima]

Gracias como siempre pro vuestra ayuda !!!

---

---

PD: Con la ayuda de Mateo mi código así y funciono lo que andaba preguntando !!! Todo gracias al usuario @Mateo.

public class LinkedListPruebaEnlazada {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<String> paises = new LinkedList<String>();

    paises.add("España");
    paises.add("Colombia");
    paises.add("Mexico");
    paises.add("Perú");

    LinkedList<String> capitales = new LinkedList<String>();

    capitales.add("Madrid");
    capitales.add("Bogotá");
    capitales.add("Mexico DF");
    capitales.add("Lima");

    System.out.println(paises);
    System.out.println(capitales);
    System.out.println("============================================");
    System.out.println("La LISTA ya enlazada es " + paisesCapitales(paises, capitales));
}

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
static <String> LinkedList<String> paisesCapitales(LinkedList<String> paises, LinkedList<String> capitales) {

    LinkedList<String> paisesCapitales = new LinkedList<String>();
    int size1 = paises.size();
    int size2 = capitales.size();
    int maxSize = Math.max(size1, size2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        if (i < size1) {
            paisesCapitales.add(paises.get(i));
        }
        if (i < size2) {
            paisesCapitales.add(capitales.get(i));
        }
    }
    return paisesCapitales;
}}
```

Comment: Supongo que no sabes usar Generics, el chiste es que puedes usar la función con una LinkedList de cualquier tipo. Si mi respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla. No es necesario que edites tu pregunta para mostrar cómo te quedó el código a menos que sigas teniendo problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo que también sirve para listas normales es agregando los elementos individualmente.

Así:

```
static <T> LinkedList<T> combinarListas(LinkedList<T> lista1, LinkedList<T> lista2)

    LinkedList<T> listaCombinada = new LinkedList<T>();
    int size1 = lista1.size(), size2 = lista2.size();
    int maxSize = Math.max(size1, size2);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
        if (i < size1){
            listaCombinada.add(lista1.get(i));
        }
        if (i < size2){
            listaCombinada.add(lista2.get(i));
        }
    }

    return listaCombinada;
}
```

Comment: Gracias !!! Ya lo adapte a mi codigo y funciono de maravilla !!! Una nueva cosa que aprendí.